# How to filter a column into different parts of a row when equal to something in SQL?

Tags: mysql, sql, join

I have 2 tables,
tblEmployee

| EmployeeCode | Name |
| --- | --- |
| 12 | Bob |
| 1 | Alan |

tblApplied

| EmployeeCode | Type | Quantity |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 12 | AL | 2 |
| 1 | M | 1 |
| 1 | AL | 3 |
| 12 | AL | 2 |
| 12 | M | 1 |

I want to return a format where i get rows grouped by name:
Name, Sum(Leaves of Type AL), Sum(Leaves of Type M)

Any Idea how to write this query?
Heres what i tried, im still new to this

```
SELECT Name, 
CASE WHEN a.Type = ‘M’ THEN SUM(a.Quantity) END AS Medical
CASE WHEN a.Type = ‘AL’ THEN SUM(a.Quantity) END AS Annual
FROM tblEmployee e inner join tblApplied a on e.EmployeeCode = a.EmployeeCode     
GROUP BY Name
```

Comment: You should try something before asking for help

Comment: Then you should upload what you have tried and maybe someone can help you to improve it

Comment: @nacho i have added my snippet above

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're really close. I think you're looking for:

```
select e.name
    , sum(case when a.type = 'AL' then quantity else 0 end) as al_quantity
    , sum(case when a.type = 'M' then quantity else 0 end) as m_quantity
from tblEmployee e
inner join tblApplied a on e.EmployeeCode = a.EmployeeCode
group by e.name
```